# Present XIB viewController with navigation bar (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, xib

This is the code I'm using

```
var xibvc = TestXibViewController()
var navb = UINavigationController(rootViewController: xibvc)
self.presentViewController(xibvc,animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I'm tying to present xibviewcontroller with a navigation bar, It gives me this error

> reason: 'Application tried to present modally an active controller

although, it works fine if i try pushViewController

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code makes no sense. What is `navb` for? You create it and then you never use it.

You probably meant to say:

```
self.presentViewController(navb,animated: true, completion: nil)
                           ^^^^
```